# How can I use std::optional to return a NULL value?

Tags: c++, std, stdoptional

How can I return a value, similar to null, with `std::optional`?
My function receives an int index as parameter to iterate through a list, if the index value is not valid, how this `std::optional` can be used to return a value similar to null?

Comment: `return {};` doesn't work for you?

Comment: That's pretty much the whole point of `optional`. So I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: If `std::optional` doesn't quite fit your use case (which isn't described in detail), you might consider using `std::variant` with `std::monostate` as one of the variant types.

Answer (score 16):

`nullptr` is to pointers what `std::nullopt` is to `std::optional`.